# how to access static file from same directory in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am trying to access the static file from the same directory but it is not working problem is it isn't loading the image in the live server

```
app.use('/static',express.static('/public'))
```

Here public is the main directory where I creat 'css'& 'img' folder and put my 'js' and 'html'file.
Before I used to access the file out side of the same directory from where I creat a css and img folder & inside those folder I creat a 'css' file and put a image . on that time it was working properly but when I put my 'js' and 'html' in the same directory where I creat my 'css' and 'img' folder it is not working means server is creating but in the 'HTML' file the 'image' is not loading in the live server.
hear is the code:

```
const express= require('express')
const app= express()
app.use('/static',express.static('/public'))

app.set('view','./public/view')
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('user  accessed')
    
})
app.listen(5000,()=>{
     console.log("server is running at 5000")
})
```

Comment: Is changing `express.static('/public')` to `express.static('public')` solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to hear right answer you need to provide as more as possible information about your problem. For example, you need to provide at least folder structure of your app, files which you want to include to your app and paths which you use. And another point for you, why not to use best-practice solution which suggested by node js express creators? Here is express app generator https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html . If you keep to use the best practice solution then you will not have such questions.